# Limiting the camera screen space that a user can use

Tags: ios, iphone, tesseract

I am using `Tesseract OCR` in the application that i am developing. when the camera interface is displayed in front of the user, i want to limit the camera screen space using which the user can click the photo.
I have to do this because the user is required to snap only a 10 letter word. if the user is allowed to use the full screen, then unwanted things can ruin the OCR reading.

Please help.. I am really stuck here.